# How to add more than one argument in terminal/cmd while biulding flutter app or what ever

Tags: flutter, dart, cmd, terminal

When I run `flutter build apk  --split-debug-info --no-sound-null-safety` it's building with null safety (The second argument is not executed)

Comment: `apk` is the second argument, is that therefore what your problem is?

Answer (score 0):

I believe the problem is that you are not providing a value for `--split-debug-info`, try adding a value to the argument like so:

```
flutter build apk  --split-debug-info=v1.1.1/ --no-sound-null-safety
```

and just replace v1.1.1 with whatever valid folder name you want